# How to propagate the try catch block for Checked Exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I have basic doubt in Java Exceptions

i.e., All checked exceptions extends from `Exception` class and Unchecked Exceptions extend from `RuntimeException`.  But Runtime Exception also extends from `Exception`.

But why to propagate `try`... `catch` block with checked `Exceptions` but not in Unchecked Exceptions?

Comment: Not all unchecked exceptions extend from RuntimeException. Apart from that I am unsure as to what you are asking - are you wondering how the Java compiler enforces the requirement that checked exceptions be declared or handled?

Comment: I think that is a really good question, also Error and its subclasses are unchecked. I'm not sure but I think they're defined in the compiler to be checked or unchecked.

Comment: Yes.But Iam trying comparing with  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,null pointer Exceptions etc

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should add different `catch` blocks for each specific type of exception you intend to handle.  If you're trying to handle (by rethrowing) checked exceptions, then you should know which type of exceptions to rethrow -- just add a `catch` block to rethrow each of those exception types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking, "How can I catch `Exception` but not `RuntimeException` ?

You probably should not be trying to do that.  You should catch specific types of exceptions when possible.  If you need to handle all errors, then you should catch `Exception` and that catches everything.*

You would rarely want to do `catch (NullPointerException)` because if you ever know that you can have a `null` then you should check for it.  If your code is causing `NullPointerException` or `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` then you should fix the code so that it no longer throws those.

This code should show you how to do what you asked about:

```
public static void throwSomething(Exception throwMe)
{
    try {
        throw throwMe;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

        // Check if the object is a RuntimeException
        if(ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
            // Throw the same object again.
            // Cast to RuntimeException so the compiler will not
            // require "throws Exception" on this method.
            throw (RuntimeException) ex;
        }

        System.out.println("Caught an instance of a " +
                ex.getClass().toString());
    }
}
```

*Actually, `catch(Throwable)` will catch everything including `Error`s.

Comment: RuntimeException has a Exception super Class.But Checked Exception can be put try...catch block.But Unchecked Exception will not why?

Comment: What do you mean?  `catch(NullPointerException e)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is this:

```
try { 
    //do stuff
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
} catch(SpecificCheckedException e) {
    //handle
} catch(Exception e) {
    //handle
}
```